# Visual Studio is moving breakpoints on a C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

2019 VS is moving breakpoints. From a GIF below you can see that a breakpoint is set on a line `225` after I hit `Debug` the breakpoint is being moved to a line `227`. Also when I press `F10` (step over) the lines are being skipped as well.

[image]

**I did research and discovered possible reasons of the problem:**

- Enabled optimization
- Outdated source code
- Disassembly code is different from the source code
- The compiled binaries were not compiled with the current source code

**None of the above is true.**

Fun enough that the problem occurs on our remote building machine only. Local builds are OK.

So what could be the reason?

Comment: @drescherjm nope everything is up to date

Comment: care to post all your compiler flags?

Comment: @Mikhail: Hum - I suspected that which is why I took the comment down. We both know that something is being cached unexpectedly here. Your mission is to find that (MS do put some stuff in AppData - not as bad as NetBeans but close), and kill it. Good luck.

Comment: @Bathsheba Okay, thank you!

Comment: How do you connect to the remote machine? Is it through Microsoft Remote Desktop? TeamViewer? NetSupport Manager? Could the actual problem be just a display image updating issue?

Comment: @heapunderrun through RDP, and the reason why I do this is because tests are failing on this machine. Not UI tests.

Comment: This seems to be a BUG, I suggest you go to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=62&entry=problem) to report this problem.

Comment: Are you really sure that none of the above possibilities is true on that remote system? I see no reason why running visual studio on a remote system (e.g a build server) should behave differently than local.

Comment: @PMF I`m sure. We have multiple remotes and the only one has the problem. I suppose the environment on the machine is broken.

Comment: Yea, if it only happens on one particular system, it's probably something with that machine.